# Show the set of all infinite subsets of the positive integers is not enumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Approaching this proof as usual, i.e., assuming that the set of all infinite subsets of all positive integers **is** countable, and then deriving a contradiction.

So, by my assumption for the sake of contradiction, there is an enumeration of the set of all infinite subsets of the positive integers. I need to construct a set that can't possibly be in this enumeration, and this is where I'm stuck -- I'm having trouble thinking of a particular set to show this. Any hints towards how I could prove this would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Use diagonalization.

Comment: See [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

Comment: Hint: show the set of all finite subsets of the positive integers *is* enumerable. Then, if the infinite subsets were enumerable, then the set of all subsets, being the union of the preceeding sets, would also be enumerable.

Comment: @TheoBendit So, the power set is the union of all finite and infinite subsets of the positive integers. And if the power set was enumerable, then the infinite subsets would be enumerable as well, so i would have to show that the Power set of all positive integers is not enumerable as well?

Comment: @MattyS11 The power set of $\Bbb{N}$ is not enumerable. In fact, Cantor's theorem basically states that the power set of a set has strictly greater cardinality than the set itself. Try a diagonalisation argument. But, if you can show the finite subsets are enumerable, and assume the infinite subsets are enumerable, that would imply the power set is enumerable too, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let true(x) = 1 if x is true, 0 if x is false.

For any subset $S$ of
$\mathbb{N}$,
let
$a(S)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} true(n \in S)2^{-n}
$.

Then $a(S)$ is a real number
between 0 and 1 and,
conversely,
for every real number $r$ between
0 and 1
there is a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$
such that
$a(S) = r$.
(Just look at the binary expansion of $r$.)

Therefore the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$
has the same cardinality as the reals,
and is therefore uncountable.

Note:
I am sure that this proof is well-known,
but I discovered it on my own
after a few seconds 
of looking at the problem.

Comment: The more standard approach is to suppose a surjection $a$ from a set $S$ to $P(S)$ exists, and consider the subset $\{s \in S : s \notin a(s)\}$, Russel's Paradox style.

Comment: What I like about my answer is that it is not a proof by contradiction. Instead, it constructs a 1-1 mapping between the desired sets and a set know to be uncountable (reals in (0, 1)).

Comment: Well, it is, but I see this proof more of a proof that $[0, 1]$ is uncountable, using the more pure diagonal argument that $P(\Bbb{N})$ is uncountable. Either way there's an indirect proof somewhere, and your argument is a direct bridge between them.

Comment: Note that $a$ is *not* a bijection.

Comment: I think it is if finite subsets are made infinite by replacing the last 1 with 01111...